# Add Facebook to Pidgin on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, pidgin

I tried integrating Facebook in Pidgin using `XMPP` and `facebook(XMPP)` but it was not working, I am getting `Not Authorized`. I also saw purple-facebook but it is only till Ubuntu 15.10 (see [this](https://jgeboski.github.io/#package-repositories)). Is there any way to  get facebook working in Ubuntu 16.10 on Pidgin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pidgin has dropped support for Facebook XMPP as of version 2.12, together with a bunch of other deprecated services. See: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/pidgin-drops-facebook-xmpp.

However, according to that same source, Purple-Facebook is still available, only not at the link you give. Instead, get the plugin here: https://github.com/dequis/purple-facebook/wiki

Comment: I tried building purple-facebook but maybe I dont have some libraries

Comment: Tell us what you tried, and what doesn't work, in a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to add face-book chat to pidgin. directions I am putting here can be found at the following links. I am posting links as a resource.

First you need to install the tools. by pasting following commands in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
sudo apt-get install cvs subversion git-core mercurial
sudo chown $USER /usr/local/src
sudo chmod u+rwx /usr/local/src
sudo apt-get install libpurple-dev
sudo apt-get install libjson-glib-dev
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev **(not necessary for me)**

git clone https://github.com/jgeboski/purple-facebook.git
cd purple-facebook
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
mkdir -p ~/.purple/plugins
cp pidgin/libpurple/protocols/facebook/.libs/libfacebook.so ~/.purple/plugins
```

[Compiling things on Ubuntu the Easy Way](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo)

[Purple Facebook GitHub](https://github.com/dequis/purple-facebook/wiki)

in addition-after installing Pidgin would not open. After running pidgin in the terminal. I received the error "could not load overlay scrollbar". If you are not using Ubuntu Unity then you can solve this by removing overlay-scrollbar.

sudo apt-get purge overlay-scrollbar

Comment: Thank-you so much.  It's been years since I've had facebook working on pidgin.  Makes chatting on my dodgy old laptop much easier (facebook in a background tab would slow her down considerably).